# JavaFX: Unwanted jagged lines after PerspectiveTransform()

Tags: javafx, line, transform

After doing a [Perspective Transform](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html) on a grid (A Pane with a few [Lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html) in it), the result (specially the more "distant" lines) is not ideal as seen in the image:

[image]

Currently I am using "StrokeType.OUTSIDE" and it helped a little bit. Increasing the line width isn't an option since closer lines will be far thicker than the others (well, this is perspective drawing, in the end).

I kind of understand why that is happening, but I'm wondering if there's something I can do to avoid this behaviour.